# Windows 10 dual monitor wallpapers post Creator Update (v1703)

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

Ever since the creators update, the command I normally use no longer works:
`control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper`

Technically one can go in the modern settings, choose pictures and then right click on them while they're on the small 5-picture wide strip and choose which monitor. ([Woe to those with more than 5 monitors then.](https://www.tenforums.com/customization/82116-creators-update-cannot-set-different-wallpaper-per-monitor.html))

But this means I have to go to through the process twice, because every time you browse for a picture it gets put on both monitors. This is unnecessarily involved and tedious.

Is there some way, free program or hidden windows control that makes this process easier?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Creators Update, you can open the classic Desktop Background control page using this command:

```
shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper
```

Compared to the modern Settings, the classic page is easier for setting up multi-monitor wallpapers.

Comment: Much easier indeed. Thank you. Further, if one wishes to create a handy shortcut to run this command, you need to put the following in the Target field: `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper`. May also change the icon (the default icon is located in `System32\themecpl.dll`)

Comment: Also, make sure you run this in the `Run Task...` window, not in `Powershell`. In Fall Creator's Update, you no longer have direct access to the old Command Prompt, unless you use the `Run Task...` window, and since you're there, just copy/paste the following answer's command into the prompt without having to call on `cmd` and run the command there, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

There's an even easier way built into the update. Go into the Personalize menu and select Picture as the background, then right click on an image and it will let you select which monitor to use it on.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to cycle wallpapers.  I have an entire folder and I like them to change every 6 hours or so to keep things fresh.